# How to use the useEffect hook with the useBlockProps hook in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Please help.

The following error is returning when useEffect hook is used however I need to use this hook to fetch WP API.

```
Error: Minified React error #310; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=310 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at bb (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:101:34)
    at Object.vh [as useCallback] (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:108:415)
    at c.useCallback (react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:29:406)
    at xe (data.min.js?ver=c5f9378263e5eea9d870764c8fc1dd1b:2:21762)
    at w (block-editor.min.js?ver=54657317be78fb1c246c72b38dc2ed0e:26:78595)
    at Edit (edit.js:67:25)
    at Le (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:100:3)
    at Re (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:113:271)
    at Pj (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:233:55)
    at di (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:168:305)
```

Alternatively if I remove the {…useBlockProps()} then the code is working fine again. That means I cannot use both of this two hooks at the same time.
You can look at my code:

```
// WP dependencies
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import apiFetch from "@wordpress/api-fetch";
import { addQueryArgs } from "@wordpress/url";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { useEffect } from "@wordpress/element";
import "./editor.scss";

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    useEffect( () => {
        apiFetch({
            path: addQueryArgs(<code>wc/store/products/</code>, {
                per_page: attributes.itemCount,
                category: attributes.categoryID
            }),
        }).then((items) => {
            setAttributes({
                productItem: items,
            });
        });

    }, [] );

    if (!attributes.productItem) return "loading...";

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            {attributes.productItem.map(item => {
                return (
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can see one example for useEffect in WordPress block

```
const componentRef = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(
        (callback) => {

        // Here you can put code
        },
    );
    props = useBlockProps( { ...props, ...componentRef } );
```